# how to plot last 5 days of Previous VWAP on intraday chart

Tags: pine-script

i want last 5 days Previous VWAPs of symbol in intraday chart, plotting line on intraday chart for indian stock market.
Tried for 2 days VWAP but not getting for 2 more than 1 day of previous vwap

```
indicator("Current and previous day VWAP", shorttitle = "CVWAP & PVWAP", overlay = true)
///User i/p///
ShowPrevVwap = input.bool(true, " previous day vwap")
///Start = input.timeframe("D") - kept for temperory
bool newSession = na
newSession := bool(ta.change(time("1D")) ? 1 : 0)
/////vwap Calculation/////
var vwapsum = 0.00
var volumesum = 0.00
var v2sum = 0.00
vwapsum     := newSession    ?   hlc3*volume      : vwapsum[1]+hlc3*volume
volumesum   := newSession    ?   volume          : volumesum[1]+volume
myvwap      = vwapsum/volumesum
//ploting Vwap////
plot(myvwap, "Current VWAP", color = color.rgb(0, 68, 255), linewidth = 2)
///Pvwap Calculation///
var prevwap = 0.00
prevwap := newSession ? myvwap[1] : prevwap[1]
//ploting pVwap////
plot(ShowPrevVwap?prevwap:na,"PreviousVWAP",color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255),linewidth = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/Faq.html#get-a-5-days-high

Lookback 5 days from the current bar

Comment: Please include the relevant code from your link in the answer, otherwise this risks being deleted as a link-only 'not an answer'.

Comment: @Gu5tavo71  sir, can you help in detail how to execute given script in answer, as it only shows only 1 higesht level on chart i need previous all 5 levels of VWAPs On intraday Chart. thank you for you kind help